# How to remove duplicates from Multivalued Fields in SOLR?

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, solr5

I tried the solutions listed in the below question.

[Removing Solr duplicate values into multivalued field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306272/removing-solr-duplicate-values-into-multivalued-field)

I'm using dataimport handler and creating multiple values for the field using RegexTransformer.

My sql returns this for column FOO

> Johnny Cash, Bonnie Money, Honey Bunny, Johnny Cash

and I store it to the multivalued field foo using splitBy=","

```
<field column="FOO" name="foo" splitBy=","/>
```

and it's stored in the multivalued field as such

> {"Johnny Cash", "Bonnie Money", "Honey Bunny", "Johnny Cash"}

I've added this to the solrconfig xml

```
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="distinctMultiValued" default="true">
    <!-- To remove duplicate values in a multivalued field-->
    <processor class="DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldRegex">foo</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />        
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I've also tried fieldName in place of fieldRegex and tried *oo instead of foo, but the duplicates remain.

Does this have something to do with the RegexTransformer?

I also have an update chain with `TrimFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory` than runs without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by moving the UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory to the existing `<updateRequestProcessorChain>` block I had.

```
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="skip-empty" default="true">
    <!--  Next two processors affect all fields - default configuration -->
    <processor class="TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="fieldRegex">.*oo</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

SOLR documentation [UpdateRequestProcessorChain](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor)

> At most one processor chain may be configured as the "default". if no
>   processor is configured as a default, then an implicit default using
>   LogUpdateProcessorFactory and RunUpdateProcessorFactory is created for
>   you. Supplying a default processor chain may be the only way to affect
>   documents indexed from some sources like the dataimport handler.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to mention full class name in process class and `<lst name="fields"> <str>multivaluedfield</str></lst>.` like

`<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.UniqFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <lst name="fields">
                <str>multivaluedFieldXYZ</str>
            </lst>
        </processor>`

Comment: That won't work. The fields option was deprecated as of SOLR 5.

Comment: In schema file add this filter to your multivaled field type definition `<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>`

Comment: Doesn't it just remove duplicate tokens. It doesn't remove duplicate values from the field in the query results, does it?.

Answer (score 0):

I am using solrJ to bind documents, and to avoid duplicated values I defined my multivalued field as a HashSet.

@Field("description")
public Collection description = new HashSet<>();